# Written with StackEdit

Tags: discussion, markdown

So, I've noticed on a few posts, that they have been "Written with StackEdit".  StackEdit seems to be a fancy Markdown editor located at http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/.

Anyway, I've seen this at the bottom of posts:

```
> Written with [StackEdit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/).
```

I'm not sure if StackEdit is adding this or if the users are.  But, I don't think it's appropriate to have this on the bottom of posts.  It seems like spam/shameless promotion to me.

When I see this, I usually edit it out.  I was just curious if anyone knows about StackEdit, and where this line is coming from (and if it's appropriate to be in posts).

I've found posts by searching on Google for:

> "Writen with StackEdit" site:stackoverflow.com

<sub>For the lazy: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Written+with+StackEdit%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Asuperuser.com+OR+site%3Aserverfault.com+OR+site%3Aaskubuntu.com+OR+site%3Astackexchange.com+-site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com</sub>

EDIT: It seems that StackEdit is adding this line to new documents (Click the "new document" button in the upper right).  Is it right for them to be doing this?  I still think it's spam to have that on all posts made by the tool.

Comment: StackEdit opens every new document with that statement in a quote. It's users who just select the entire source to copy and paste in the markup. No idea why the hell someone would write an answer in an external editor when it's basically a standalone app that makes use of the same editor as the site itself, but then as a moderator I encounter all kinds of strange behavior.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: So, I guess there's nothing we can do about it?  Is it ok for me to edit that out of posts?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I just went and edited it out - apparently the same user has been using it to write their most recent answers and constantly leaving it there.

Comment: You can also use the site search to find these posts. Simply find `"written with stackedit."` including the quotes.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: But I Google everything!  Even how to Google things.

Comment: Keep an eye out on [other sites in the SE network](https://www.google.com/search?q=Written%20with%20StackEdit%20site:stackexchange.com) that might also suffer from this scurge.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn That is because the editor in Stack Exchange __IS NOT__ side-by-side.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn was I the user? By the way people use stackedit because it is better than the StackOverflow editor. The side-by-side preview and full screen editing are missing from the stack overflow editor. StackEdit.io also uses ACE editor which is a clean and powerful in-browser text editor.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is entirely appropriate to edit that out of any answer (or question) you see it in.  It is not contributing positively to the quality of that post.

Comment: Should we possibly ask the tool to not include that in new posts?

Comment: @RocketHazmat You can ask; they're under no obligation to do anything about it.  It's an external site, they're free to do what they want.

Comment: True.  I agree, but it just seems like spam to add that to posts here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sure, it basically is, but it's not like you can prohibit people from using the site.  There really isn't much to do besides remove the content when you see it.  If it becomes a real problem *maybe* that text could have some sort of blacklist applied to it, but somehow I don't see the site getting enough traction to get to that point.

Comment: I don't know the developer but StackEdit doesn't seem to have ever  been intended as an external editor *for* Stack Exchange posts. It just happens to use the same technology that SE does, and people just happen to be using it instead of the in-house editor. Neither does SE even endorse StackEdit.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a problem, and I don't think it will be, but it was just something I noticed :)

Comment: This, or comment to the author to remove it themselves. I think it should be obvious that this is not wanted.

Answer (score 32):

I'm the creator of StackEdit, which is designed to write Markdown documents and blog posts, not to write questions/answers on Stack Exchange. As mentioned in StackEdit's settings, this footer is to encourage users to support the project by adding a backlink in their documents/posts. It's there by default but it's fully removable/customizable.

Since it's a free application and it has no budget for advertising, I'm opposed to removing it from the application. However I will add few words about this issue in the settings or in the welcome document.

Comment: Not having money to advertise isn't a reason to spam

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a variation on spam. I'd remove it if I were you, and maybe put advertising in the web app instead. Awesome app, BTW.

Comment: Guys, it's unreasonable to blame the creator of the editor because  clueless users inappropriately blindly copy-paste. As he says -- this wasn't intended as a Stack Exchange post editor (although given Stack Exchange's inadequate implementation of drafts, it's more useful for that than it should be).

Comment: Or give users the choice to opt-in to unwittingly add backlinks on your behalf instead of having to opt-out by default

Comment: @random Unwitting? [It's pretty difficult not notice when you're creating a new document](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gjiu.png), and you can get rid of it with a simple `CTRL+A`, or change your default document contents to something else in the settings (no registration required).

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: That's exactly what I meant to say under Servy's answer yesterday.

Comment: @JeremyBanks It's called StackEdit and uses a logo that is clearly reminiscent of Stack Overflow's, but it is no way intended to be related to Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Gilles I agree that it could be intended to take (potentially unfair?) advantage of users' positive associations with Stack Exchange, but that's different than being intended to be used with Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange users are a tiny fraction of Markdown users today, and StackEdit supports some features like GitHub's code block syntax that aren't supported on Stack Exchange. If *I* were making a tool intended to mainly to be used with Stack Exchange, it wouldn't look like this.

Comment: (Although a fork of StackEdit using Stack Exchange's v2.2 API could be pretty awesome, particularly with a browser plugin tweaking the "edit' and "add question/answer" links so that the default editor/drafts feature was entirely replaced. Such a fork should not include any type of signature, but there may also not be much reason for anyone to include one: the v2.1 API automatically included a credit to the application used to post a comment, and v2.2 may do the same thing for posts.)

Comment: It's an **awesome** app, as I already stated in other assorted posts in other SE sites. Which brings me to say here, what I've said in another post/comment: **`benweet`**, you [have to disclose your affiliation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) when answering with a recommendation to the App. The arguments raised here in this comment thread tilt the balance in two sides, one excellent and other not so.

Comment: Fair enough @brasofilo

Comment: @random: He's not spamming.  Users of his app who don't remove the link are (unintentionally) spamming.  Just edit their posts to remove the sig, and tell the user to remove it in the future, or convert it to a comment.

Comment: @benweet, How can we integrate StackEdit into our websites?