# Editing large blocks of content

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

When editing large blocks of content for questions or answers, I found that the browser page may not be able to display both editing window and preview window, **when editing is taking place**.

This always happens when there are large amount of content before the editing point, as the preview window can not scroll down (instead, if one wants to check the preview, it is always needed to scroll down and find the modified locations), this is annoying if the formatting is complicated (e.g., editing formulas).

I just wonder if there is any external plugin in Emacs or Vim that shares the same formatting syntax as Stack Overflow, so that I can edit the content like writing latex and once finished, post on the web.

Or alternatively, how do you deal with large contents editing?

Comment: I sometimes use a small page with [PageDown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) for offline working or [Stack Edit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/).

Comment: http://stackapps.com/questions/2245/stack-exchange-side-by-side-edit-and-preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I know the felling, the scroll thing doesn't get it right.

Maybe this Question should go to [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/), 
but maybe here it reaches a wider audience,...

[It's already being used in the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202156/written-with-stackedit#comment642744_202209), and it blatantly rides on the Stack wave & the logo is plain ugly;
**but**, after discovering and becoming a heavy user of Mardown, 
this is my toy/tool of choice: [**stackedit.io**](https://stackedit.io).

[image]

Our data can be synced in a variety of ways, but it's based on [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage),
if we reset the browser (or it does by itself) and don't have backups, bye, bye.

<sup><sub>*PS: I don't have any affiliation with the product.*</sub></sup>

Comment: Just a word of caution that you may want to add to your post: Stackedit uses an extended version of markdown with a handful of extra features (Tables, for instance), so some documents created in it won't translate exactly unless you change the settings a bit.